# Where do I find the org.restlet.android.jar?

Tags: android, restlet

I have downloaded the android editions for the restlet api's and see org.restlet.jar in libs but when I look at code eamples from other people they reference org.restlet.android.jar. Where do i find this jar? Or is it not needed? Apparently I am missing something very basic here.

thanks
Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find them packaged in the sample project found at the bottom of this page: http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/275-restlet/266-restlet/269-restlet.html

Comment: Thanks for the link slayton, that was the example i was referring to. So my next question becomes what is the difference between the org.restlet.jar and the org.restlet.android.jar?

Answer (score 0):

The org.restlet.android.jar is equivalent to the org.restlet.jar from the Android edition.